# select multiple values from same column

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

```
SELECT b_lastname, b_firstname, cscart_profile_fields_data.value AS VAT
FROM cscart_user_profiles
INNER JOIN cscart_profile_fields_data ON cscart_profile_fields_data.object_id = cscart_user_profiles.user_id
WHERE cscart_profile_fields_data.field_id =64
AND cscart_profile_fields_data.object_type = 'P'
```

I am using the code above, in order to get values from the cscart_user_profiles table but also from cscart_profile_fields_data table and especially the value field.
What i would like to do is get different values from the value field in the same query, just by changing the field_id

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

```
SELECT b_lastname, b_firstname, cscart_profile_fields_data.value AS VAT
FROM cscart_user_profiles
INNER JOIN cscart_profile_fields_data ON cscart_profile_fields_data.object_id = cscart_user_profiles.user_id
WHERE cscart_profile_fields_data.field_id IN (64, ...)
AND cscart_profile_fields_data.object_type = 'P'
```

This quere return as many rows as parameters in WHERE IN condition

or:

```
SELECT b_lastname, b_firstname, GROUP_CONCAT(cscart_profile_fields_data.value SEPARATOR ';') AS VAT
FROM cscart_user_profiles
INNER JOIN cscart_profile_fields_data ON cscart_profile_fields_data.object_id = cscart_user_profiles.user_id
WHERE cscart_profile_fields_data.field_id IN (64, ...)
AND cscart_profile_fields_data.object_type = 'P'
GROUP BY b_lastname, b_firstname
```

above query return one row with many values in VAT column separated by ; character (like CSV file)

Comment: thank you for your answer. this works, but i get the result in the same column (VAT). how could i create another column where the results of the second field_id value would be stored?

Comment: SELECT b_lastname, b_firstname, data1.value AS VAT, data2.value AS VAT2
FROM cscart_user_profiles
JOIN cscart_profile_fields_data AS data1 ON data1.object_id = cscart_user_profiles.user_id
AND data1.field_id =64
AND data1.object_type = 'P'
JOIN cscart_profile_fields_data AS data2 ON data2.object_id = cscart_user_profiles.user_id
AND data2.field_id =58
AND data2.object_type = 'P' this is want i wanted to do...